# List all ansible hosts from inventory file for a task

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

For a backup I need to iterate over all hosts in my inventory file to be sure that the backup destination exists. My structure looks like

```
/var/backups/
            example.com/
            sub.example.com/
```

**So I need a (built-in) variable/method to list all hosts from inventory file, not only a single group.**

For groups its look like this

```
- name: ensure backup directories are present
  action: file path=/var/backups/{{ item }} state=directory
          owner=backup group=backup mode=0700
  with_items: groups['group_name']
  tags:
    - backup
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Thats the solution:

```
with_items: groups['all']
```

Comment: Unfortunately "item" appears to be a string rather than the inventory item.  How would you access item.inventory_hostname, for example?

Comment: Perhaps you want to access hostvars?  hostvars[item]["ansible_os_family"] for example.

Answer (score 1):

### if the purpose is to just print all the hostnames then use below command.

ansible all --list-hosts